# Content Security Policy / Subresource Integrity for <a> tags?

Tags: security, hash, content-security-policy, subresource-integrity

I host a website that allows users to download a file that is stored on a content distribution network (CDN).  The link to the file on the CDN from my site is something like `<a href=https://cdndomain.com/path/to/file>`.  I’d like to have a way for my users to ensure that file has not been manipulated by the CDN.

Of course, I can publish a hash of the file on my site (which of course is secured by SSL/TLS).  Then, after the user downloads the file, they can take a hash of the file and verify that it matches the hash published on my site.  This is not uncommon.  But, many of my users are not savvy enough to understand this process.  And, even for those that are, this process is somewhat cumbersome.  I’m looking for a more automated/convenient way to ensure that file has not been manipulated.

I know that [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) (CSP) and [Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) (SRI) are now supported by Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.  Using CSP/SRI, sites can ensure that .js files, .css files, etc., hosted elsewhere and referenced by `<script>` or `<link>` tags have not been manipulated, by including hashes of the target files in the `<script>` or `<link>` tags using the `integrity` attribute, e.g.:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

This is very convenient, because the browser checks that the hash of the target file matches the hash specified in the `integrity` attribute ‘behind the scenes’, without any user intervention.  After downloading the file from the CDN, the browser takes a hash of the file and checks that this hash matches the hash provided in the `integrity` attribute of the `<script>` or `<link>` tag.  If the hashes does not match, the browser warns the user and does not execute the script or apply the css stylesheet.

I’m looking for something similar for a resource referenced in an `<a>` tag – whereby I can specify a hash of the target resource in the `<a>` tag, and the browser would perform a similar check after downloading the resource from the CDN, but before making it available to the user, and warn the user if the hashes do not match.  But according to the MDN docs referenced above, CSP and SRI only apply to `<script>` tags and `<link>` tags, not to `<a>` tags.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: This problem can be solved by using a javascript function, served from the same server that the trusted checksum is served from, to verify the integrity of the download from the untrusted server.  See https://www.meixler-tech.com/aivwd/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Neither SRI nor CSP is really made for that; the item isn't actually being loaded on the page so neither of them will actually fire not that there's a way to specify requirements on an `<a>` tag anyway.

It's not quite the security vector either of these are made for either; these are meant to stop malicious code from being run in the browser. Once you've downloaded a file you're pretty much on your own unless it triggers the built-in Chrome "suspicious download" warning.

I would say your options are:

A) Provide a page where the user can upload the file to generate said hash for them and, while you're under the hood, might as well actually match it and generate a message that says "this matches the hash of X file!"

B) Ditch the CDN. They are by definition a Man In The Middle, so to fully trust TLS you'd need to deliver the file directly to the user or at least have full control of the CDN.

Which you pick depends on a combination of how much effort you want to put and how practical it is to ditch your CDN. Obviously A) lets you keep your CDN but is far more programming, B) is basically free of programming but could be extremely easy or completely impossible logistically.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this script https://github.com/ShopupStore/IntegrityChecker , Even though it is for image, you will get the Idea for implementing it for  tag. This script uses sha256 polyfill for the purpose, The final markup may look like this

```
<a data-href="https://cdn.example.com/1.jpg" data-hash="496aa8990b87f584dffc43e5953d38abcbc30a2edab131fd304fec43d6d9b289" data-fallback="https://example.com/1.jpg" class="link">
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.